# How to use webmatrix class within a script function

Tags: javascript, sql, html

I am playing with webmatrix with html5 startersite template. originally it manipulates database in `@{}` and it works fine.

```
@{ 
    ...
    var db = Database.Open("StarterSite");
    var user = db.QuerySingle("SELECT Email FROM UserProfile WHERE LOWER(Email) = LOWER(@0)", email);
    ...
}
```

However, I want to use query or update data within a function, and if I try this

```
<script>
    function temp(){
    ...
    var db = Database.Open("StarterSite");
    var user = db.QuerySingle("SELECT Email FROM UserProfile WHERE LOWER(Email) = LOWER(@0)", email);
    ...
    }
</script>
```

or put @ symbols before Database or db.QuerySingle, it failed. VS gave me runtime error saying webmatrix not defined at those lines.

Could anyone help?

Comment: I think I want to close this. Since it is bad idea or impossible to run sql directly at client side :)